# Letters being accepted for a double

Tags: java, swing

I have a txtbox that you put your 'income' into and then it converts and checks to see your tax etc.. (Just a simple tax calculator)

It doesn't allow any letters/special characters etc...

Although when I have an input such as **'123456d'** or **'123456f'** it calculates while ignoring the letter at the end.

It **only** works with the letters **D** and **F**

I just wanted to know how I could fix this or why this happens?

Comment: It's happening because you can add `d` to indicate double or `f` to indicate float. I think.

Comment: @shahar that what I believe, although why it is allowed when other letters are not is what is confusing me. :O

Comment: As per your question *It doesn't allow any letters/special characters etc...* then how can a user input a letter? Please explain...

Comment: @JakeB Because you don't need other letters? Does `e` work?

Comment: @Shahar `e` would only work if followed by a well-formed exponent, e.g. `e9`, `e+12`, `e-43`.

Comment: @Braj All letters, characters such as ' " ; : etc... do not work except for when a ''d'' or an ''f'' is placed after the number,

Comment: How are you restricting user to input other than digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A float or double literal is allowed to have the characters `f` `F` `d` and `D` in the end because they are part of the literal (and used to express the exact type of the variable: `float` or `double`).

The method used by Java to parse strings into floating point values can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29). You can see:

```
    if ( i < l &&
            ((i != l - 1) ||
            (in.charAt(i) != 'f' &&
             in.charAt(i) != 'F' &&
             in.charAt(i) != 'd' &&
             in.charAt(i) != 'D'))) {
            break parseNumber; // go throw exception
        }
```

To solve your problem you will need to parse the number in a different way, of check if the string ends with one of these characters and block it before the actual scanning.

Comment: Note that the suffix is accepted but completely ignored by the parser. I imagine they built in support for those suffixes to make the string syntax coincide with Java's language syntax, although I was unable to find any concrete references as to *why* they wanted to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The [implementation of `Double.parseDouble()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Double.java#Double.parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) is:

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue();
}
```

`FloatingDecimal` is an internal class, the source is [here](http://j7a.ru/_floating_decimal_8java_source.html). Looking at the source, you will see that the suffixes 'D', 'd', 'F', and 'f' are accepted but ignored (lines 1233-1236).

This is likely present so that the string format coincides with Java syntax [which allows D/F suffixes on literals](http://www.javaying.com/2006/12/whats-java-literal.html) to specify the type. As Radiodef helpfully points out in comments, it is documented at [`Double.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). In particular:

> Note that trailing format specifiers, specifiers that determine the type of a floating-point literal (1.0f is a float value; 1.0d is a double value), do not influence the results of this method.

And in the regex there: `[fFdD]?`

If you need to explicitly disallow these types of strings, the workaround would be to make sure your input string does not end with D/d/F/f before parsing it as a double.

Comment: It's documented (though not obviously) at [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Well you can actually thank @ZouZou since [I just got the link from them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309958/exception-to-number-format-exception-with-d-and-f#comment33900426_22309958). : )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the input data is nummeric only (or ., then you will need to check each character for validity.  Sounds like homework, so no code.

You can check for validity by considering a state diagram:

1. before any decimal point .. accept only numbers and stay in  state 1
   if decimal accept and move to state 2
2. if number and not more than 2 digits

   ....